# Bootstrap "data-toggle=tab" disables url

Tags: python, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask

Got myself a bootstrap navbar like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" >
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('user', username=current_user.username) }}" data-toggle="tab">User</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('home') }}" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                {% if current_user.is_anonymous %}
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

but for some reason when i'm using the "data-toggle=tab" option the tabs start working but they don't redirect me to given urls, when i remove the "data-toggle=tab" urls work fine again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to redirect to a link. No need to use `data-toggle="tab"`. the href in an `<a/>` tag with `data-toggle="tab"` attribute means you're using bootstrap tabs which has a js counter part.

Comment: if you want to make a 'disabled' styling for anchor tag, yes you can achieve that by using css.